# How to get int value with reflection, without having any object

Tags: java, reflection, minecraft

How may I get int value? I don't have object. http://hastebin.com/ovudovotah.avrasm I need to get `this.d.as`, what's way for that? Can someone put me on way? I tried everything, but I always stucked with object in all other tutorials, I saw people has object to for the field#get method, but I don't have object..

Comment: If you don't have any object, then there is no "this" and thus "this.d" also doesn't exist. To me it seems that you are asking:

"I need to get the color of a car, but I don't have a car."

Comment: Well that class is being loaded by main program, but I just need to hook in and get the int. How may I do that? Basically I need from this class: http://hastebin.com/ticeyifujo.avrasm There is `int as;`

Comment: The class is loaded? What does that mean? You need a reference to the actual object somehow to get it's value. Without any reference to it, you cannot access it.

Comment: Well it's minecraft server, when I start it's being automatically loaded I meant. Can you put me on way to get `int as;` from  http://hastebin.com/ticeyifujo.avrasm ?

Comment: It seems that you want to start programming Java - but so far; you have **no** idea what that actually means. Suggestion: instead of starting with code examples that are too complex for you right now: start with a tutorial aimed at **beginners**, like http://www.javabeginner.com/
It simply does not make sense to explain to ask "what does A and B and C mean" ... when you do not even know what "A" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you HAVE a reference to an object, let's call it x, you can get the value from a public field quite easily:

```
Object x = ...; // get it from somewhere
try {
x.getClass().getDeclaredField("as").get(x);
} catch(Exception ex) {
 //do error handling here
}
```

Of course, that's only basic and only works for public fields that easily, which is not good style.